# Disallow sub folders of an allowed folder?

Tags: robots.txt, subdirectory

I am using Codeigniter to build my website.  Many of my URLs contain multiple slashes and look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/friend/mack/johnson/1023
```

My problem is that Google wants to index several different variations of this URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/user/friend/mack/johnson/
http://www.example.com/user/friend/mack/
http://www.example.com/user/friend/
http://www.example.com/user/
```

Unfortunately, these URLs don't go anywhere.  Is there a way to disallow the  sub-folders of an allowed folder within a robots.txt file?  I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
Disallow: /user/*
Disallow: /user/*/*
Disallow: /user/*/*/*
Allow: /user/*/*/*/*
```

I am a bit afraid to try this.  I really have no idea how the search engines will react.

**About the answer:**

It seems that the most specific rule is the one that is followed.  therefor:

```
allow: /item/results/product/*/*/
allow: /item/results/product/*/*/*/$
disallow: /item/results/product/*/*/$
disallow: /item/results/product/*/*/*/*
```

will allow

```
/item/results/product/some/thing/12345
```

and

```
/item/results/product/some/thing/12345/
```

but not

```
/item/results/product/some/thing/
```

nor

```
/item/results/product/some/thing/12345/a
```

Comment: 1. How do you know that Google wants to index them? 2. Which HTTP status gets sent when accessing these URLs?

Comment: I am getting warnings in Google Webmaster tools:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

"Over the last 24 hours, Googlebot encountered 238 errors while attempting to connect to your site. Your site's overall connection failure rate is 4.9%."

Comment: The report showed several "Not Found" and 404.  although 4% is much far from the worst case scenario, I would really like to let Google know that specific kinds of URLs will not return viable results.  The vast majority of these links return a blank page with a header and footer (1000's of them, which could ruin my SEO.)

Comment: But if you correctly send HTTP status 404, search engines already know that there is nothing interesting for them to find. There is no need to disallow 404 pages.

Comment: @unor: It's likely the problem is that crawlers aren't especially bright. They'll try to hit `/user/foo`, get a 404, try `/user/bar`, get a 404, then `/user/XXX` and every other combination they have and keep getting 404s. Then the people operating the crawler (or the monitoring code) will see all those 404s and decide to stop crawling the site altogether because it got so many 404s. Plus, a request isn't free. Having to send tens of thousands of 404 pages does consume bandwidth and other resources. Better off telling the crawler not to look where it won't find anything useful.

Comment: I am afraid of that.  I don't want Google spending too much time crawling bad links.  I already have 5000 valid links that Google can't figure out (the spider has trouble dealing with %f2 in a url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a trailing `*` is superfluous. So `/user/` and `/user/*` mean the same thing.

You should be able to write:

```
Allow: /user/*/*/*/
Disallow: /user/
```

This says to allow crawling of the subdirectories three levels down, but disallow anything else that begins with `/user/`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great.  Is there a quick and painless way to see if this (or other changes to the robot.txt file) work or don't work?

Comment: Also, should this question have gone into the webmaster forum?
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Hoytman: Yes. In the future please post such questions to webmasters. As for testing, you might try Google's Webmaster tools. They have a robots.txt checker/validator. I don't recall the link.

Comment: I just discovered that Google has a robot.txt tester.  It seems that bots will follow the most specific match that can be found.